# Referencing users when posting content to Office 365 Connector Cards

Tags: webhooks, office365connectors, microsoft-teams

How do I reference another user when posting to a Microsoft Teams channel using a webhook.  I can use the text property within the json to specify basic content body but how would I add for example

"Need to ask @Jim about this project" and have Jim receive a reference to this post?

Using the following reference as a guide https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/Reference

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatic @mentions are currently not supported in Microsoft Teams.  It's on the backlog, though, and should be coming soon.